# How does SE decide how many Mods a graduated site gets?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

I understand the process: (beta --> public beta --> graduation) and the difference between Mods pro-tem and community-elected mods.

I'm just curious as to the metrics used to decide how many mods a site gets once it becomes graduated and mods are elected?

Also, how, why and by what process might that number change over time?

My question is about number of mods for sites that have already graduated.

Comment: I think it's always three, except special cases. Since pro tem moderators were never really elected, as far as I know, they don't keep their diamond when the site is graduating and need to nominate themselves as any other user. And three is the [magic number for pro tem moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134980/152859).

Comment: Okay, but how about number of mods for graduated sites? Is it purely based on volume metrics, or is it more qualitative than that?

Comment: Not sure, hence only a comment. :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134978/296059

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default number of moderators is always three.

Whether or not a site is graduated doesn't really affect whether that number increases. There's no set formula for calculating the number of moderators, if that's what you're asking, and it doesn't automatically increase after certain periods of time.

The answers over on [How many pro tem moderators are chosen? Always three?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134978/how-many-pro-tem-moderators-are-chosen-always-three) are still completely relevant to graduated sites. There's also some information on this over at [When do moderator elections take place?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99512/when-do-moderator-elections-take-place) There are factors that go into the decision to appoint or elect more, such as the current workload (how much the moderators are having to handle), the activity of existing moderators, and how much we expect site-specific problems to arise. But the most important factor is whether the moderators think they even need more help, and if they do, they can request it. That's usually the primary trigger for adding more.

Comment: Also fair chatbot dice roll.

Comment: @TimStone: But a fair roll would be [*four*](http://xkcd.com/221/), right?